# Dynamically repeat page template in reportlab

Tags: python, templates, frame, reportlab

I am trying to generate a pdf report using reportlab in python and I have a large table splitted along a few pages. The problem is that it overwrites my footer and I would like to limit it with a frame within a page template.

How could I use `tableTemplate` everytime a new page is generated considering that I don't know the length of the table or the number of rows in a page?

Here is my code:

```
def report_pdf(self):
    buffer = self.buffer
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer,
                            rightMargin=30,
                            leftMargin=30,
                            topMargin=30,
                            bottomMargin=0,
                            pagesize=self.pagesize)
    elements = []
    table_data = gather_table_data()
    long_table = Table(table_data)
    elements.append(long_table)
    frameMain = Frame(x1=doc.leftMargin,
                       y1=doc.topMargin,
                       width=doc.width,
                       height=doc.height)
    tableFrame = Frame(x1=doc.leftMargin,
                       y1=doc.topMargin,
                       width=doc.width,
                       height=doc.height-50,
                       showBoundary=1)
    mainTemplate = PageTemplate(id='main', frames=[frameMain])
    tableTemplate = PageTemplate(id='table', frames=[tableFrame])
    doc.addPageTemplates([mainTemplate, tableTemplate])
    doc.build(elements, onFirstPage=footer, onLaterPages=footer)
    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    return pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to repeat the template every time a new page is generated but I solved the problem by increasing document's `bottomMargin` and placing the footer outside the margin. Considering that the footer is drawn directly on document's canvas it wasn't affected by the margin, while the table, as a flowable, was limited by document's margins, therefore prevented it from overwriting the footer.